# CSS Grid - make items within grid have independent height

Tags: css, css-grid

I have grid container which has the following properties:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(300px, 1fr));
grid-template-rows: 300px 300px auto auto auto;
```

I have two fixed height first rows set to 300px, but I want the next rows to not have dependent height. Meaning each item in that row I want to be `min-content`. Currently the items are expanding to the full height of the ancestor item in the same row.

This is the layout I'm aiming for:
[image: Text]

But I can only achieve this:
[image: Text]

Comment: CSS support for masonry layouts is coming, but it’s not here yet.